# Check if n-bit number is divisible by 7

Tags: circuits, arithmetic, binary

Show how to check if n-bit number is divisible by 7 in logarithmic circuit depth.

How can I construct the circuit to be able to check the divisibility?

Answer (score 0):

$8^k \cdot x \mod 7 = x \mod 7$, therefore we can split the number into groups of three bits and add these groups.

Now you use a 3-2 adder: A 3-2 adder takes three n-bit inputs and creates one n-bit output and one n-bit shifted output with the same sum: This is just done by connecting all triples of three bits with a one-bit full adder.

Now if you add three 3-bit values with bit values 421, 421 and 421, and get two sums 421 and 842, then 8 mod 7 = 1, so you move the bit at index 3 to index 0, and you turned three 3-bit numbers into two 3-bit numbers with the same value modulo 7.

Say you have a 128 bit number. Split into 43 3 bit numbers. Add 3 numbers, 14 times in parallel, and you have 28+1 = 29 numbers. Then add 9 times 3 numbers, and get 20 numbers. Add 6 times 3 numbers, getting 14 numbers, then from 14 to 10, from 10 to 7, from 7 to 5, from 5 to 4, from 4 to 3, and finally from 3 to two 3-bit numbers.

That sum x+y is divisible by 7 if x xor y is all bits zero or all bits 1.

Comment: In the third paragraph, I don't understand this section: "then 8 mod 7 = 1, so you move the bit at index 3 to index 0, and you turned three 3-bit numbers into two 3-bit numbers with the same value modulo 7." Where did we get 8 mod 7? If it equals 1, then why we move 3rd index to index 0?

Comment: 8 mod 7 _is_ 1. Always has been.So if you move any bit of x three bit positions to the right, then you change the number x by a multiple of 7, and x mod 7 is unchanged.